# Replace a string pattern with a minor modification in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a regex pattern which matches for text like "week-day", "some-thing" etc. I want to replace this pattern with "week day", "some thing".

I did something as follows:

```
Pattern alpha_only = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+\\-[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher alonly_matcher = alpha_only.matcher(token);
while (alonly_matcher.find()){
    old_val = alonly_matcher.group(0);
    new_val = old_val.replaceAll("\\-", " ");
    token = token.replace(old_val, new_val);
}
```

But this doesn't work in cases where the string contains many hyphens. For example in a string like

```
"This is some-example text with - multiple hyphens and 45-55 week-day"
```

it should not remove hyphens between 45-55 etc. How do I go about fixing this? I new to regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have all the information you need.  Just use capturing groups.

```
Pattern alphaHyphenated = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)\\-([a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher alphaMatcher = alphaHyphenated.matcher(token);
return alphaMatcher.replaceAll("$1 $2");
```

Or, simply

```
return token.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)\\-([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1 $2");
```

Of course, that compiles the pattern each time it runs.  `alphaHyphenated` above can be a compile-time constant.

Comment: This capturing groups logic was what I needed! Thanks!